# Create new columns based on string

Tags: r

Starting Point. I have a vector of strings. I don't know what they are until runtime.

```
targets <- c("value_1", "value_2")
```

Now say I have a dataframe full of stuff. Here's a min example. It so happens that there are some instances of the strings above in the first column.

```
first_column  <- c("-", "-", "-", "value_1", "value_2", "value_1 value_2")
second_column <- c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-")
df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)


     first_column   second_column
1               -               -
2               -               -
3               -               -
4         value_1               -
5         value_2               -
6 value_1 value_2               -
```

What I would like to do is add new columns to the dataframe: named after the search variable - i.e. value_1 and value_2; and set to "-" if first col does not contain the value, and equal to the value if it does. In conventional code, I'd use a forEach over the target vector...

```
     first_column   second_column       value_1        value_2                    
1               -               -             -              -
2               -               -             -              -
3               -               -             -              -
4         value_1               -       value_1              -
5         value_2               -             -        value_2
6 value_1 value_2               -       value_1        value_2
```

I've tried a bunch of things, but can't quite get it to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over the targets vector and using grepl() to check if each target string is present in the first_column of the df dataframe.

```
targets <- c("value_1", "value_2")
    df <- data.frame(first_column = c("-", "-", "-", "value_1", "value_2", "value_1 value_2"),
                     second_column = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"))

for (target in targets) {
  # create a new column with the name of the target string
  df[[target]] <- ifelse(grepl(target, df$first_column), target, "-")
}

# reorder the columns so that the target columns are next to the first_column
df <- df[, c(1, 2, 4, 3)]

print(df)
```

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this as the best answer because a) it's simple and self explanatory, and b) it makes no implicit assumptions regarding space delimitation of the first_column. Mostly because the other answers are just a bit too clever for me. I like simple!

Answer (score 1):

`lapply`-variant:

```r
cbind(df,
  sapply(targets, function(tgt) ifelse(sapply(strsplit(df$first_column, " "), `%in%`, x = tgt),
                                       tgt, "-"),
         simplify = FALSE))
#      first_column second_column value_1 value_2
# 1               -             -       -       -
# 2               -             -       -       -
# 3               -             -       -       -
# 4         value_1             - value_1       -
# 5         value_2             -       - value_2
# 6 value_1 value_2             - value_1 value_2
```

Walk-through:

- `strsplit(..)` breaks out the space-delimited words/tokens so that we can test for simple "set membership";
- the inner `sapply` does the compare of each `tgt` (from `targets`) in each row of the column;
- the outer `sapply` iterates over `targets`, returning a named list
- `cbind(df, ..)` to add those two to the original `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Another loop-based solution:

```
for(i in seq_along(targets)){

  # function that detects target string by iterating with grepl

  target_in_row <- function(x. , targets. = targets){ sapply(targets.[i], grepl, x = x.)}

  # apply target_in_row() to each row
  # sum the resulting array to simplify the result to a vector
  # assign the vector to new columns names for the target

  df[[targets[i]]] <- colSums(apply(df, 1, target_in_row))

  # Rename the values. IF value == 1 assign target, ELSE "-"

  df[[targets[i]]] <- ifelse(df[[targets[i]]] %in% 1, targets[i], "-")
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cbind(df, sapply(targets, \(x)ifelse(grepl(x,df$first_column),x,'-')))


     first_column second_column value_1 value_2
1               -             -       -       -
2               -             -       -       -
3               -             -       -       -
4         value_1             - value_1       -
5         value_2             -       - value_2
6 value_1 value_2             - value_1 value_2
```